# Change Static Table Views like contacts app on Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, static

I know this question has been asked before, but no one has really answered it.

I am trying to make an app with a static table view and a Done/Edit button in the top-right corner. I need to be able to hide a cell when it is in one state, and display that cell when it is in the other state. Also I need to be able to add cells when the user selects something. I all ready have the bool in place to detect the change of the Done / Edit button.

So basically my question would be: how do you go about making the table view display the cell when the user presses the button, and hide it when the user presses it again.

And how to add the static cells through the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Static tableviews are...   static....  You can not add/remove rows (although you can sort of:  you can hide them by setting their hidden property to yes AND setting the row height to 0.)  Using a dynamic table would be the better route to go, as @conradShultz describes.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really looked at the static table stuff in iOS 5 because I believe that requires storyboards, which I don't use.

This can be easily accomplished with a classical grouped `UITableView`, however. In your `UITableViewDataSource` methods merely return different results based on the editing state.  If you are using the literal `editing` mode of the `UITableView` you could do something like the following (warning: typed in browser):

```
– (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([tableView isEditing]) {
        // Return number of sections when editing
    }
    else {
        // Return number of sections when not editing
    }
}

– (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView isEditing]) {
        // Return number of rows in section when editing
    }
    else {
        // Return number of rows in section when not editing
    }
}

// etc.
```

I don't recall whether the `-setEditing:` transition handles animation for you, but if it doesn't then you will want to use `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and related methods to notify the table view that the number of rows, sections, etc. has changed and that it should animate to the new layout.  Finally, if you are adding/removing multiple rows/sections, as always you probably want to wrap your work in a `-beginUpdates`/`-endUpdates` pair so that the animations are all coalesced.